# Problema com formatação de formulário

Tags: html, css, formulário, input, float

Bom dia pessoal, estou com um certo problema no formulário de newsletter de meu site.

Já fiz várias pesquisas tentando solucionar o problema, porém a falta de conhecimento da área acho que está me impossibilitando. rsrs

O formulário basicamente leva Nome, Email e o botão de envio.

Por padrão vem um embaixo do outro e gostaria de converte-lo para um do lado do outro.

Consegui chegar a esse ponto usando float, porém os campos estão "colados" um no outro e eu precisaria colocar uma margem.

O código está da seguinte forma:

```
    <div class="campos" id="nome" style="float:left" style="margin:5px" style="width:200px"
     style="align:left">
  <p>
    <label>Nome</label>
    <input type="text" name="FNAME" placeholder="Digite seu nome."
    required="">
</p>
</div>

<div class="campos" id="email" style="float:left" style="margin:5px" style="width:200px"
     style="align:center">
 <p>
   <label>E-mail</label>
    <input type="email" name="EMAIL" placeholder="Digite seu e-mail"
    required="">
</p>
</div>

<div class="campos" id="inscrever" style="float:left" style="width:200px" style="align:right">
<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Inscrever">
</p>
</div>
```

O endereço do site é: http://159.203.130.115/wesley/wordpress/

Poderiam me ajudar a dar uma "arrumada"?

Comment: Já usou margin e padding?

Comment: Bom dia WMomesso, sim, porém não apresentou mudanças.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adicione no css este código:

```
.campos {
    margin: 5px;
}
```

que resolverá seu problema, tente inserir na div  onde tem o botão de submit uma

```
<label>&nbsp;</label>
```

isso resolverá o problema de alinhamento do botão.

Comment: Essa label resolveu um dos problemas, realmente alinhou o botão. Obrigado.

Comment: O CSS não resolveu o outro problema? você queria os campos um pouco separados ou de alguma outra forma?

Comment: Não resolveu, justamente gostaria de separa-los um pouco.

Comment: Você deve estar colocando o CSS em um arquivo que não é chamado nessa página ou pode estar em cache, faz o segunte nas divs onde tem o campo nome, email e botão coloque <div class="campos" id="nome" style="float:left; margin: 5px;"> faça isso com as 3 divs (lembre-se de manter os ids delas).

Comment: Magnifico! Chegou exatamente ao ponto que precisava. Sou muito grato a você. Obrigado.

Comment: Imagine, só peço que sinalize a resposta como útil, assim ela pode ser vista por outras pessoas com o mesmo problema que você e ajuda-las.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode adicionar uma `margin-right` (margem direita) para os `inputs` (campos) do formulário, conforme exemplo abaixo:

```css
#inscricao input {
    margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="inscricao">

  <div class="campos" id="nome" style="float:left" style="margin:5px" style="width:200px"
       style="align:left">
    <p>
      <label>Nome</label>
      <input type="text" name="FNAME" placeholder="Digite seu nome."
      required="">
  </p>
  </div>

  <div class="campos" id="email" style="float:left" style="margin:5px" style="width:200px"
       style="align:center">
   <p>
     <label>E-mail</label>
      <input type="email" name="EMAIL" placeholder="Digite seu e-mail"
      required="">
  </p>
  </div>

  <div class="campos" id="inscrever" style="float:left" style="width:200px" style="align:right">
  <p>
      <input type="submit" value="Inscrever">
  </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Coloquei todos dentro de uma `div` para não aplicar a `margin` aos demais `inputs` da página, mas somente aos `inputs` que estão dentro da `div` 'inscricao'.

Comment: Bom dia Leandro, primeiramente muito obrigado pelo retorno.

Contudo, fiz o solicitado e não resolveu.

Comment: @WRTEletronicos Pode ser que esteja em cache no navegador, por isso não apresentou nenhuma mudança. Sugiro que, após inserir o CSS que mencionei acima, atualize a página através dos atalhos CTRL + R e CTRL + F5 para que as alterações no CSS sejam carregadas corretamente.

Comment: Leandro, deu certo aplicando as modificações citadas acima pelo Guilherme.

Creio que eu estava errando na repetição de "Style" toda hora, suponho que seja isso que estava afetando.

A modificação simples de :

<div class="campos" id="email" style="float:left" style="width:200px"
       style="align:center style="margin-right:15px">

Para:

<div class="campos" id="email" style="float:left; margin: 20px;">

Resolveu a questão